# Qt Signal Slot Architecture Unwanted Infinite Loop

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I've problem with qt signal-slot system.

First I've created a class which is called System in Singleton pattern, so I can access it's instance where I want. System has a signal SelectionChanged.

I've a list widget and I am connecting it's itemSelectionChanged signal to my custom slot which is called onSelectionChanged. In onSelectionChanged slot, I am emitting System's SelectionChanged signal. There is no problem yet.

In my software design, a selection of object(s) can be used by many GUI widgets or custom classes and System's SelectionChanged signal can be emited by widgets other then the list widget.

So I am creating a slot called OnSystemSelectionChanged in the list widget then connect it to the System's SelectionChanged signal. The OnSystemSelectionChangedSlot is like this.

```
void MyListWidget::OnSystemSelectionChanged(QObject *sender)
{
    if (sender == this) return;
    // Then I want to get a list of selected objects and set them as selection of this widget like this:
    this->SetSelection(System::Instance()->GetSelectedObjects());
}
```

But the problem is when I start to set the list widget's selected items, it is going to emit itemSelectionChanged signal and my onSelectionChanged slot will be called. Then the slot will emit System's SelectionChanged signal and then OnSystemSelectionChanged will be called too. It will stop through sender parameter but there is no method for setting list widget's selected items at once.

How can I figure this problem out.

I hope I did explain my problem well. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Spelling and grammer errors are corrected.

Comment: As a similar with BartoszKP's second solution, I've found a solution too. QObject has a blockSignals() method to prevent emitting inner signals.

Answer (score 12):

There are a few ways of dealing with this in Qt.

### Idioms

1. Use multiple views with one underlying model. This handles propagation of changes to multiple view controls automatically and you don't need to do anything extra. You can use [`QDataWidgetMapper`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatawidgetmapper.html) to link "plain old" widgets to the data elements in a model. I'd say that this should be the preferred way of doing things. Having an underlying model for all of your UI is a step in the direction of good software design anyway.
2. When propagating changes between data models, implement both a `DisplayRole` and an `EditRole`. The views will nominally modify the models using one of the roles (say, the `EditRole`), while you can, programmatically, modify the models using the other role (say, the `DisplayRole`). You handle the `dataChanged` signals from the model in your own slot, properly dealing with the roles, and call `setData` on the other models with the other role. This prevents the loops.
3. For controls that are not `QAbstractItemView`s, implement two signals: one emitted on any change, another one emitted only on changes based on keyboard/mouse input. This is the interface exposed by `QAbstractButton`, for example: the `toggled(bool)` signal is the former, the `clicked()` is the latter.  You then only connect to the input-based signals.

   Your own  code must propagate programmatic changes to all the interlinked controls, since changing one control from your code won't modify the others. This should not be a problem, since well designed code should encapsulate the implementation details of UI controls from rest of the code. Your dialog/window class will thus expose its properties in a way that's not coupled to the number of controls showing a particular property.

### Hackish Let's-Hope-They-Won't-Become Idioms

1. Use a flag inhibiting signal emission ([Bartosz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20743561/1329652)).
2. Break the signal/slot connections for the duration of the change ([Bartosz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20743561/1329652)).
3. Use `QObject::blockSignals()`.

Comment: I've understood clearly. First and second solutions must be the correct way of handling multiple views. I've no knowledge about these idioms. But I will learn them and use as soon as possible. Thanks for this attentive answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible solutions I can think of:

- add a flag which makes possible to ignore particular signals:

```
void MyListWidget::OnSystemSelectionChanged(QObject *sender)
{
    if (sender == this || inhibitSelectionChanged)
        return;

    this->inhibitSelectionChanged = true;
    this->SetSelection(System::Instance()->GetSelectedObjects());
    this->inhibitSelectionChanged = false;
}
```

- [disconnect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#disconnect) the slot from the signal, and reconnect it after changing the selection:

```
void MyListWidget::OnSystemSelectionChanged(QObject *sender)
{
    if (sender == this)
        return;

    this->disconnect(SIGNAL(SelectionChanged()));

    this->SetSelection(System::Instance()->GetSelectedObjects());

    this->connect(
        this, SIGNAL(SelectionChanged()), 
        this, SLOT(OnSystemSelectionChanged(QObject*)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advices. The first one will be emit itemSelectionChanged but I can use flags to not emit System's SelectionChanged in onSelectionChanged.

For the second one, it is important to know the cost of connection and disconnection, I think.

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü Costs are unimportant in general in such applications. Only when you find that there is a problem with performance, then investigating the issue is justified.

Comment: I understand but depending on a state it can be called ten times in a second probably the cost of it will be a few microseconds so it can be used too.

Answer (score 2):

I found my solution in QObject::blockSignals() method. It will prevent emitting signals from the list widget while I am setting selected items.

Thanks for all the answers and solutions especialy for BartoszKP's. This solution is looks like the official way of his first solution.

Comment: Didn't know about this function, that's very interesting, thanks!

Comment: It looks like your solution, Qt just documented before you post :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem: you've tried to cut corners and created a singleton. Not a classic case for singleton.

Signals and slots are used for notifications, each object notifies interested objects about what it did or to reflect its new state.

I'm suggesting changing the design as follows:

- No singleton signal.
- Each Object has its own signal and slot for a relevant event (e.g. selection change).
- The application or a higher level object (that created the widgets/objects) performs the signal to slot connection. If those widgets are placed in a list, this is very simple.

Comment: It can be MainWindow, thanks for the advice, is there any other solution?

Comment: You of course can use a patch like suggested in BartoszKP's answer but you'll regret it in the long run. It leaves a lot of room for error. My suggestion is a simple design that will make your code easy to understand too.

Comment: I thought a little more and I found your solution painful especialy when I wanted to add more widgets.